# Using local variables with "apply" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, inheritance, scope, apply

**Why "show" method is not able to access "text" variable here ?**

```
// @constructor A
var A = function(){

    //alerts some text variable
    this.show = function(){
       alert("Hello")
       alert(text);
  }

}

//@constructor B
var B = function(){

  //local text variable
  var text = "World";
  A.apply(this); // "show" method will get attached to B
}

var obj = new B();

//now calling show of B's object.
obj.show(); //returns error.



//Expected output
alerts "Hello"
alerts "World"

//Actual output
alerts "Hello" 
ReferenceError: text is not defined
```

Am I missing something here ?
Shouldn't the "text" variable be accessible to B's "show" method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike C++ or Java, Javascript doesn't have an implicit `this`.

If a function (like `show`) refers to `this.foo`, then only the value of `this` depends on how the function was called.

However, if `show` refers to a variable directly (like `foo`), then it can mean either:

- a local variable, if it's defined using `var` at the function scope;
- a variable from a closure, if the function is being defined inside another function that happens to define it with `var` (closure gets created at the moment of function definition),
- a global variable otherwise.

In your case, the third case applies. `show` can't access `text` because it is defined in a totally unrelated scope.

Comment: Thanks for this .."show can't access text because it is defined in a totally unrelated scope."

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `text` as property of `B` constructor  `this.text = "World";` something like this.

```
var A = function(){

    //alerts some text variable
    this.show = function(){
       alert("Hello")
       alert(this.text);
  }

}

//@constructor B
var B = function(){

  //local text variable
   this.text = "World";
  A.apply(this); // "show" method will get attached to B
}

var obj = new B();

//now calling show of B's object.
obj.show(); //returns error.
```

Comment: Thanks Suman Bogati. But I know what the solution is, I was just willing to know why(this particular behavior) it was happening.